# Usage of 'using' causes ObjectDisposedException in creating list of EventData

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I normally send data to event hub as follows..

```
var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString);
using (var edata = new EventData(encoded) { PartitionKey = mypkey })
{
    edata.Properties[EventDataPropertyKeys.MyKey] = myvalue;
    await _eventclient.SendAsync(edata).ConfigureAwait(false);                        
}
```

Today I thought of trying to send the data via batch and tried to create a list of EventData objects as follows..

```
List<EventData> eventDataList = new List<EventData>();

//in a loop
var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString);    
using (var edata = new EventData(encoded) { PartitionKey = mypkey })
{
    edata.Properties[EventDataPropertyKeys.MyKey] = myvalue;
    eventDataList.Add(edata);
}
```

But when I check the eventdatalist objects, I find SerializedSizeInBytes property of EventData object showing

```
'This eventdata instance has already been disposed'
```

and while accessing throws..

```
'eventData.SerializedSizeInBytes' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: See Danny Chen's answer. `using` blocks are used to automatically dispose of objects once they are not needed anymore. If you need your object outside of a `using` block, don't use one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the first code snippet, you send `edata` inside the `using` block. But in the second snippet, you put `edata` in a list, and after that, loop through the list and send each item after the `using` block, where the item `edata` is already disposed.